# Is there any DB server that can optimize the following query?

Tags: sql, query-optimization

Let's say I have the table `my_table(id int not null primary key, datafield varchar(100))`.  Query 
`SELECT * from my_table where id = 100` performs an index seek. If I change it to

```
SELECT * from my_table where id+1 = 101
```

it scans the whole index (index scan) (at least it does it in SQL Server and Mysql). Is there any DB server which 'understands' that `id +1 = 101` is the same as `id = 101-1` ? I do realize that it's not a typical database operation, and server doesn't have to perform any math in such cases, but I wonder if it's implemented anywhere?

Thanks
**UPDATE**
So far I've tried SQL Server 2008 Enterprise, Mysql 5.1, 5.5. SQL Server shows clustered index seek and clustered index scan respectively. Mysql `explain` shows `ref:const, key:primary, rows:1` and `ref:null, key:null,rows: #total number of rows in the table`

Comment: are you sure about that, just tested with SQL 2008 R2 and in both cases did only index seek, not a table scan, what versions have you tried it with?

Comment: @ K Ivanov: I've just tried it again : 1.Clustered index seek; 2. Clustered index scan. Sorry, in my question it should say "scans the whole index" instead of "whole table". I'll change it. +1 for pointing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> id +1 = 101 is the same as id = 101-1

No it isn't.  What if the +1 overflows the id?

Comment: You may be right about overflow, I'm not sure about promotion rules for sql expressions, but, for example, `id + 0 = 100` cannot overflow, can it?

Comment: Would you write code that looks for someone adding the 0 literal to something in the hopes to optimize that case?  Would that optimization help the situation that spawned this question?

Comment: Ok, I agree that `+0` doesn't make much sense. I'm still not sure that it's impossible to detect possible overflows/underflows in advance if it's the only reason for not doing so. Anyway, thanks for good point. +1.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this with PostgreSQL 9.0 and it does not use an index unless I create one on `(id - 1)`.

So with the following index definition

`create index idx_minus on my_table ( (id - 1) );`

PostgreSQL uses an index for the query

```
select *
from my_table
where id - 1 = 12345
```

Comment: Thanks for info, it's good to know. However, it probably means that if I change `where id-1 = 12345` to `where id -2 = 12345` I should create another index ?

Comment: @a1ex07: Yes, that's correct. So if your "+ value" changes with every query, you won't be able to create a proper index.

Comment: @a1ex07 - I tried this with an indexed persisted column in SQL Server and it didn't get used unless I actually selected the column by name. Not sure whether Enterprise Edition would have substituted it in. TBH I think it would be a complete waste of development time for the SQL Server developers to implement something that would rewrite predicates like this. I'd much rather they just got on with tackling more important issues like implementing the `OVER` clause.

Comment: @Martin: I do agree that it's not an important issue; I believe it should be a number of reasons not to implement this feature (so far I inclines to David B's explanation). As for practical usage, I think it might be useful in some complex join conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting.

You can add Oracle Release 10.2.0.1.0 to your list (not able to rewrite the query).

```
create table t(
   id
  ,x
  ,padding
  ,primary key (id)
) as
select rownum              as id
      ,'x'                 as x
      ,lpad('x', 100, 'x') as padding
  from dual
 connect by level <= 50000;
```

Query 1.

```
select id
  from t
 where id = 100 + 1;

----------------------------------------+
| Id  | Operation         | Name        |
-----------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |             |
|*  1 |  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN| SYS_C006659 |
-----------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------    
   1 - access("ID"=101)
```

Query 2.

```
select id
  from t
 where id + 1 = 101;

--------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name        |
--------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |             |
|*  1 |  INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| SYS_C006659 |
--------------------------------------------    

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------    
   1 - filter("ID"+1=101)
```

Query 3.

```
select x
  from t
 where id + 1 = 101;

------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  |
------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |     1 |
------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------    
   1 - filter("ID"+1=101)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to try it. +1

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this instead (assuming you don't want the server to do the math for calculating the actual ID you're looking for)?

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = (101 - 1)
```